# Angular 2 how do I set begin value of a select box?

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to have in all my select boxes the value of `"Select an option"` I have fixed it for the first one like this:

```
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrototypeSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPrototypeChange()">
      <option *ngFor="#p of prototypes" [value]="p.selector">
           {{ p.selectorName }}
      </option>
  </select>
```

and in the component:

```
private selectedPrototypeSelector: string = "Select an option";
```

And I created a fake object in my `expression.array.ts` like this:

```
 {
        selector: "Select an option",
        selectorName: "Select an option",
        constraints: "Select an option"
    },
```

But I would like to set it for all the select boxes and here is the template for the second second select box:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="expression.constraint">
     <option *ngFor="#constraint of prototype.constraints" [value]="constraint">
         {{ constraint }}
     </option>
</select>
```

Where I bind it to the object expression, how can I fix this?

This is what i want to achieve I did this in photoshop:

[image]

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lFLDz1?p=preview) to get a better overview.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the expected value in the `constraint` property of the `expression` object:

```
addExpression() {
  let expression = new Expression();
  expression.constraint = 'Select an option';
  // This could also be set using another variable
  this.expressions.push(expression);
}
```

**Edit**

Since the `selectedPrototypeSelector` property of the expression component is used to select the value, you need define it as an input

```
@Input()    
selectedPrototypeSelector: string = 'Select an option';
```

and provide the expected value when using the component:

```
<expression *ngFor="#expression of expressions" 
            selectedPrototypeSelector="arrivalDate" <------
            [prototypes]="prototypes"
            [expression]="expression" 
            [expressions]="expression.children">
</expression>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/LjfiY4?p=preview.

Comment: it is not setting the value of the select box

Comment: Yes, in fact, you need define the `selectedPrototypeSelector` property as an input and provide the expected value when using the expression component... I updated my answer

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the effort man! But I what i really want is to set both of the select boxes to the value of: `Select an option` I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Add an initial value for `selectedPrototypeSelector` on your component.

For example you could have:

```
  public barList: string[] = [
    'bar1',
    'bar2',
    'bar3'
  ];
```

and then:

```
foo: Foo = new Foo(
  this.barList[0];
)
```

where:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(
    bar: string
  ) {}
}
```

So, on your template in order to have the first element of barList as initial value for the select box you must:

```
<select [ngModel]="foo.bar">
  <option  *ngFor="#b of barList" [value]="b">{{b}}</option>
</select>
```